# Get name of contact by nickname in Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider

I have some problem with Contact Provider. I have a nickname, which stored in string variable *text*. I want to get name and surname of user, which have some nickname. But it's something wrong with my code:

```
String _string = "no name";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME + " = " + text, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, null);
int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    _string = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
}
```

I have error "bind or column index out of range".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                      new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.DATA1 + "=?",
                      new String[] { text },
                      null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) String nameOfContact = cursor.getString(0);
```

This code will return to you first contac name with nickname wich stroed in *text* string.